# How can I validate @RequestParam using javax validations annotation

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I have used *javax validations* for `@RequestBody` and it works. say

```
public void putData(@Valid @RequestBody DataDTO dataDTO)
{
   .....
}

class DataDTO
{
   @Digit(integer = 10, fraction = 3)
   private BigDecimal value;
}
```

But what if we do not have `@RequestBody` or `DTO` and just a single parameter.
For example 
I have a following method in controller,

```
public String getCityWithTemprature(@RequestParam BigDecimal temptrature)
{
   ....
}
```

How I can validate it using `@Digit` of *javax validations* Or any other best way to do it

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *Improvement* filled in official spring jira. [See](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380) this link to jira.